# php mysql redirect not working

Tags: php, mysql

I apologize if this has been a repeat, but I haven't seen anything with this problem.

I'm trying to redirect a user back to the main site after he/she logins in.

this is my form code,

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" name="input" action="login.php" method="GET">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" id="Username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                        </div>
                        <div id="loginPasswordGroup" class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                            <span id="loginPasswordGlyph"  class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" id="loginUser" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
                    </form>
```

this is my login code,

```
<?php

    include("dbconnect.php");
//LOCK the table
 mysql_query("LOCK TABLES LOGIN WRITE;");
 $log = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["Username"]); 
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$log'");
if ($result >0)

    header('location: http://bdpastudents.com/~t4645202/2015-2016/Message%20Board/Message%20Board%20Lab%201/');
            exit;

else {

    echo "<h2>Invalid Username or Password!<br></h2>";
};

 //UNLOCK the table
 mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES;");

?>
```

every time I try to login in, I get an error. Php is still quite confusing to me so a little light shed on this would be great. thanks.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: There goes your database...

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: All it says is that there is an error on line 13, and does not tell me anything else.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `mysql` library was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0. You may want to use `mysqli` instead. The first thing I notice is that you're missing a MySQL resource object:

```
$con = mysqli_init();
if (!$con->mysqli_real_connect("host", "mysql_user"
        "mysql_password", "database")) {
    echo "could not connect";
    exit;
}
$log = $con->real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$log'");
if ($result !== false && $results->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<script>window.location = 'http://something';</script>";
} else {
    echo "Invalid user";
}
$con->close();
```